# XmlPullParser name expected exception

Tags: java, android, xml, exception, xmlpullparser

I try to read a XML file created by my app using this code:

```
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(new StringReader(data));
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
{
    switch(eventType)
    {
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
        {
            String tagName = xpp.getName();
            // do something
            break;
        }
        case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
        {
            // get text...
            break;
        }
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
        {
            // do something
            break;
        }
    }

    eventType = xpp.next();
}
```

but at first, when **eventType** is START_DOCUMENT, **next()** function throws exception: *org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: name expected (position:START_TAG @2:2 in java.io.StringReader@41084cc8)*

Do you have any idea why?

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<0>
  <createTime>1419453655800</createTime>
  <editTime>1419453655800</editTime>
  <color>2</color>
  <text>ooooo</text>
</0>
<1>
  <createTime>1419453586197</createTime>
  <editTime>1419453605679</editTime>
  <color>1</color>
  <text>uuuuuuuuu</text>
</1>
<2>
  <createTime>1419453358866</createTime>
  <editTime>1419453597124</editTime>
  <color>2</color>
  <text>yyyyyyyyyy</text>
</2>
```

Comment: Your XML document is not well formed as it does not have a single root element.  You should fix this before trying to parse it.

Comment: @kjhughes ok, thank you for pasting the XML

Comment: So, should I move all elements in a dummy root and everything will work? I'll try it

Comment: Yes, minimally you'll need a single root element.  (It's technically not even XML without a single root element, which is required to be well-formed.)  If any other problems arise, let us know.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, make your numbered tags start with a letter such as e1, e2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make your XML [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) by giving it a single root element and making element names start with letters, not numbers:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<top>
  <e0>
    <createTime>1419453655800</createTime>
    <editTime>1419453655800</editTime>
    <color>2</color>
    <text>ooooo</text>
  </e0>
  <e1>
    <createTime>1419453586197</createTime>
    <editTime>1419453605679</editTime>
    <color>1</color>
    <text>uuuuuuuuu</text>
  </e1>
  <e2>
    <createTime>1419453358866</createTime>
    <editTime>1419453597124</editTime>
    <color>2</color>
    <text>yyyyyyyyyy</text>
  </e2>
</top>
```

Comment: You were right. It worked after inserting text before numbers. But I have a question: when I call getName function, I get end-line and space characters as well. Is it normal?

Comment: No, that's not normal.  For START_TAG, END_TAG, and ENTITY_REF events, `getName()` should return Strings, which should never have spaces or newlines; for other events, `getName(`) should return null.  I'd post a new question with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that specifically shows `getName()` returning EOL and spaces.

Comment: You are right. When a tag doesn't have text (like <top> or <e0>) getText() returns "\n  ". Sorry but I didn't get your last sentence. Thank you